# AJAX escaping '+' symbol, invalid syntax

Tags: json, ajax, escaping

I need this part of my url:

"Regular+Season" printed as "Regular+Season" instead of "Regular%2BSeason" to the console.

I have currently developed a ajax function and I keep getting invalid syntax errors due to this issue

Ajax code:

```
  function loadStats() {
  $.ajax({
    url: 'http://stats.nba.com/stats/leagueLeaders?&callback=?',
    jsonpCallback: 'jsonReturnData',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data: {
      LeagueID: '00',
      PerMode: 'PerGame',
      Scope: 'S',
      Season: '2016-17',
      SeasonType: 'Regular+Season',
      StatCategory: 'PTS',
      format: 'json'
    },
    success: function(response) {
      console.log(response);
    }
```

Comment: `%2B` is completely correct.  You should change your server to handle URL encoding.

Comment: `"Regular%2BSeason"` is  `"Regular+Season"` but encoded using `encodeURIComponent`